# Looking for Oracle function count from 1 when new different field shows up back to 1 and count up

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am new to SQL. I am looking for a function, I have been looking around but I can not find what I want.

so After I execute,

I would like to show,

```
    V   x
    a   1
    a   2
    a   3
    b   1
    b   2
    b   3
    c   1
    c   2
    d   1
    e   1
    e   2

select V, ____ over (order by V) as x from my-table
```

I checked row_number,rank,dense_rank, but these does not work, Does any different function exist?

Comment: `over( ...  order by v)` will do nothing within a group (or partition) by the same `v` (of course: within such a group or partition, `v` is the same for all rows!) If ORDER BY is required, as it is sometimes, the intent would be clearer - with the same result - if written as `order by null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT v, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY v ORDER BY v) x
  FROM my-table
```

RESULT

```
V          X
- ----------
a          1
a          2
a          3
b          1
b          2
b          3
c          1
c          2
d          1
e          1
e          2
```

Comment: RIght. However, see the note about `order by null` I added in a Comment to the OP's question.

Comment: Correct. Any value can be used since it will do nothing and the syntax needs to have order by in it.